# Android Studio project build.gradle options at a module level

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I have the following code in the project build gradle file.

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

gradle.projectsEvaluated {
    tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
        options.compilerArgs.add('-Xbootclasspath/p:C:/Users/<user name>/AndroidStudioProjects/<application name>/app/libs/myjar.jar')
    }
}
```

}

I would like to add the options.compilerArgs.add line at a module level in the build.gradle file. So i copied and pasted the following bit, after the Android clause, but got the fatal exception

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail to connect to camera service

```
android {
   ...
}

gradle.projectsEvaluated {
    tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
        options.compilerArgs.add('-Xbootclasspath/p:C:/Users/<user name>/AndroidStudioProjects/<application name>/app/libs/mycamera.jar')
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it hack for provided scope dependency?

Comment: It's to give precedent over my libraries namespace to androids namespace